# R geom_bar with each bar the mean value of subsets of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

If I have a column with numeric values and I want to create a bar chart with each bar as a mean value of the subset of that column, how can that be done?
For example,

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
x1_df <- data.frame(x1)
x_set1 <- mean(x1_df$x1[1:5])
x_set2 <- mean(x1_df$x1[6:10])
x_set3 <- mean(x1_df$x1[11:15])
x_set4 <- mean(x1_df$x1[16:20])
```

How do I create 4 bars with the mean value heights?

Answer (score 1):

You can take `mean` of every 5 values and then plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x1_df %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/5)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(x1)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(grp, mean) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but if I have a data frame with multiple columns and the above is one of them, then this solution does not work for me. (Consider that I am not creating a column with data, the data already exists.) 
Can you please explain?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you update your example to have multiple columns? Do you want to take `mean` of multiple columns?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @sam I don't know which experienced users told you it is better to delete duplicate questions. But questions should not be deleted if they are duplicate. They should be closed as duplicate. See this meta post for reference https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do this with `barplot`

```
barplot(with(x1_df, tapply(x1, as.integer(gl(length(x1), 5, 
          length(x1))), FUN =  mean)))
```

-output

[image]